# Include dynamic paths in FitNesse

Tags: fitnesse

Is there a way to include dynamic paths in FitNesse ?

Assuming I have the following structure

```
Credentials
  - Local
    - Customer
    - Admin
  - Staging
    - Customer
    - Admin
TestLogin +
```

In my `TestLogin` page I would like to something like

```
!define PLATFORM (Local)
!include .Credentials.${PLATFORM}.Customer
.... 
My Test Tables
```

I've also (unsuccessfully) tried defining the path:

```
!define PATH (.Credentials.${PLATFORM}.Customer)
!include ${PATH}
```

**Edit**
The accepted answer, strictly speaking, doesn't answer the question (seems it's not possible) but provides a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that your trying to achieve something like: the [example of why one would want symbolic links in the user guide](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.SymbolicLinks)?

Would it be acceptable to switch the 'axes' of your reuse (i.e. create a single suite containing TestLogin and use a symbolic link to include this in the hierarchy for each environment where each hierarchy defines some variables (used in TestLogin) that are specific to that environment)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
!define PLATFORM {!include -c <SampleRoot.Credentials.Local.Customer }
${PLATFORM}
.... 
My Test Tables
```

? (note the extra space at the end of the `!define`)
Depending on the Fitnesse version this might or might not work :)
I'm using v20150814.

Comment: That still doesn't allow me to add variables in the path. I want to get the `.Local.` part as a variable defined at the start. I.e `!include -c .Root.${variable}.SubSubWiki`

Comment: But you can define different values PLATFORM in different hierarchies.