# FitNesse: how to add a single test page to multiple test suites

Tags: fitnesse

how to add a single test page to multiple test suites?

Please note that I want to get the suite name in SuiteSetUp during the test run. Is this possible in FitNesse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how to add a single test page to multiple test suites`
You simply create a page under your suite and include the test page.

Not sure about the second questions, sounds like you're trying to do dynamic include and that's not possible.
I.e.

```
!include $mySuite
```

where `$mySuite` is defined in `SuiteSetUp`. At least [I couldn't find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114193/include-dynamic-paths-in-fitnesse).

You might want to consider generating the data in the `SuiteSetUp` and use something like [parametrized includes](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.AcceptanceTestPatterns.ParameterizedIncludes).
Personally I found them to work better with [symbols](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables).